# Incrementing Counter for ID Generator

Tags: c#, mysql

The Scenario:

I have this situation, in the cinema ticket booth, there are two customers went in booth 1 and the other in booth 2. They watch at the same cinema. The last ticket series sold is recorded in the database was 87990, when the 2 POS (installed in the ticket booth) get the last ticket series, they got 87990, so the ticket given to 2 customers is the same; which is 87991. These problem occurred if the two computers do the transaction at exactly the same time.

here is the process:

```
lastticket = getlastticket();      //get lastticket series
updatelastticket(lastticket + 1);  //update counter
```

I would like to ask if you can give some recommendation on how to fix this problem.

Currently, all i have is a database that holds the last ticket series sold per cinema.

Comment: Sounds like a synchronization issue. How about using locks?

Comment: Is your `ID` an autoincremented primary key?

Comment: After selecting the last ticket series, you need to `READ LOCK` that field until it has been updated. Then the second SELECT Query will wait for that UPDATE before executing. The best way to go about this depends on your MySQL Engine.

Comment: @zerkms: its just and INT value, manually auto-incremented everytime  a ticket is sold.

Comment: @kerrek: its a nice one to try; please help me whats the algorithm for locking.

Comment: @rechie: so make it autoincrement

Comment: @rechie: Maybe post a little bit of code pertaining to the ticket issuing process. Basically combine all the comments here; make the row id AUTO INCREMENT and make the read+update (or read+insert) operation atomic by locking the table.

Comment: @zerkms: I guess, auto-incrementing is applied only when you insert a new data having an auto-incremented ID. But what is the situation here is updating the counter itself. Thank you so much  zerkms for your response.

Comment: @kerrek: I guess that is what i am looking for, a read+update operation; specifically lock+read+update+releaselock process.

Comment: @rechie: I don't know how to do that off the top of my head, but there's guaranteed to be tons of information on the internet, even within the MySQL documentation, I'm sure.

Comment: @PaulPRO: thank you paul. I will do some research in your suggestion about READ LOCK

Comment: another option - just prefix the counter with the POS, basically make it POS1-87990. this way it is still unique without the need for any lock etc.

Comment: @Yahia: I hope i can do that but ticket series being given should be uniform. i cannot give POS1-87990 and POS2-87990 ticket series. Thanks Yahia!

Comment: if that is not possible then your best option is an autoincrement, if that is not possible then you really need to work out the locking

Comment: @Yahia: You're right, i guess my last option is locking.

Comment: @all: What happens if a request is trying to access a locked table? Does the request waits until the table is unlock or database server will give an error? [mysql server is used in this project]

Comment: @rechie The request waits until the lock is released

Answer (score 0):

remove parameters of updatelastticket();

```
public int updatelastticket()
{
UPDATE   Ticket_Table SET Ticket_ID = Ticket_ID + 1;
int last_ticket_id = SELECT MAX Ticket_ID FROM Ticket_Table;
return last_ticket_id;
}
```

I mean , update the ticket id then return it;

Comment: thank you for this response. But without locking the table, it may happen that there will some query updating the lastticket befre you select the max ticket id;

Comment: @rechie
you are right. lock table , make your update , select , ..etc , then remove the lock ..

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot lock the table in the database or use an auto increment type column, can you write a small gatekeeper daemon that is the only access to that row in the database and have both POS systems call that daemon instead of direct calls to the DB by the POS systems?  The daemon could then serialize the requests.